# Is it usual when I am scrolling UICollectionView with empty cells the memory is growing

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uicollectionview

Hi just wonder about if it is normal when I am scrolling UICollectionView with empty cells the memory is growing? How can I control this? 
[image]

Does it lead to memory leaks? Any explanation will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No..the cells are just reused everytime you scroll in the collection view. It may be possible if something is retained via a strong reference if you use custom data to create a cell.

Comment: Are you registering a `UICollectionViewCell` for reuse? Can you show an example?

Comment: @sdasdadas Thank you, however I have already found the mistake it was because of cell weren't deallocated while scroll happens.Will provide detailed answer with description later.